# COPY from named stage fails with `no such file or directory`

Tags: docker, dockerfile

wondering who could help since all my searching seems to be fruitless.

Given this docker file:

```
# ------------ STAGE WKHTMLTOPDF

## madnight container needed due to qt, must have wkhtmltopdf with patched qt
FROM madnight/docker-alpine-wkhtmltopdf as madnight

# ------------ STAGE BASE LAYER
## Create a *base* image with all system dependencies
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine AS base

ENV REDIS_VERSION 4.0.2
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE ${PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE:-1}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_ENABLE ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_ENABLE:-1}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST:-""}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT:-9000}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTO_START ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTO_START:-1}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK:-1}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_IDEKEY ${PHP_XDEBUG_IDEKEY:-"debugit"}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_PROFILER_ENABLE ${PHP_XDEBUG_PROFILER_ENABLE:-0}
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_PROFILER_OUTPUT_DIR ${PHP_XDEBUG_PROFILER_OUTPUT_DIR:-"/tmp"}

## FPM Dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    --virtual .dd-build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        postgresql-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        icu-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        libpng \
        libjpeg \
        libpq \
        libxml2 \
        icu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        gd \
        pdo_mysql \
        pdo_pgsql \
        zip \
        opcache \
        bcmath \
        intl \
    && pecl install -o -f \
        redis \
        xdebug \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable \
        redis \
        xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=debugit" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_host=$LOCAL_IP" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    # WKHTMLTOPDF Dependencies
    && apk add --update --no-cache \
        libgcc \
        libstdc++ \
        libx11 glib \
        libxrender \
        libxext \
        libintl \
        libcrypto1.0 \
        libssl1.0 \
        ttf-dejavu \
        ttf-droid \
        ttf-freefont \
        ttf-liberation \
        ttf-ubuntu-font-family \
    # Clean up
    && apk del .dd-build-deps \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY --from=madnight /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin

# ------------ STAGE TAPIOCA PHP DEPENDENCIES
## Install Tapioca PHP dependencies
FROM base AS withPHPDependencies

ENV APP_DIR = /source-code
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

COPY ./ ${APP_DIR}
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        curl \
        git \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer \
    && composer install  --optimize-autoloader

# ------------ STAGE TAPIOCA FRONT END DEPENDENCIES
## Install Tapioca Front-End dependencies
FROM node:6-alpine AS withFEDependendcies

WORKDIR /source-code

COPY --from=withPHPDependencies /source-code/ ./

# Since NPM loves to go crazy let's redirect everything to http for github
RUN git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com && \
    npm install && \
    npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt --unsafe-perm && \
    npm install -g https://github.com/hellofresh/lentil.git --unsafe-perm && \
    yarn --ignore-enginesyarn --ignore-engines && \
    ./lentil all angular,sass,libs,js

# Development Image
FROM base

ENV SOURCE_DIR = /source-code
ENV APP_DIR = /server/http

WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

COPY --from=withFEDependendcies /source-code ./

VOLUME ${APP_DIR}

RUN cp ./docker/php-fpm/tapioca.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ \
    && mkdir -p /var/log/ordering \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/log/ordering \
    && chown -R www-data:root /var/log/ordering \
    && chmod -R 777 ${APP_DIR}/app/cache
```

running `docker build -t dev-test:latest -f docker/dev/Dockerfile .` fails with

```
 ---> a15292733770
Step 23/31 : COPY --from=withPHPDependencies /source-code/ .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9eaa20ed309e8ffc27461fcf7809b9187a117de2dc318071713d696f27fdc078/merged/source-code: no such file or directory
```

The local files get copied to the `withPHPDependencies` because the `composer install` step runs without any issues. I also commented out everything in the `.dockerignore` and ran `docker system prune -a`

Not sure what else I could check.

Comment: What happens if you `docker build --target withPHPDependencies test:withPHPDependencies .` and then `docker run --rm test:withPHPDependencies ls -la /source-code`

Comment: @BMitch `ls: /source-code: No such file or directory` wonder why it's not maintaining the directory

Comment: If I were to guess, composer did it, but I don't know that tool to say that with any authority. If you comment out the composer line and the directory is there, then you probably want to ask composer this question instead of the docker tag.

Comment: I'm a blind mouse. it's because I'm using `ENV foo = /dir`. Too much time in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ack!! I'm blind.

Dockerfile doesn't use `=` to define environment variables. Once I removed them everything started working.

Thank you @BMitch for the faster troubleshooting suggestion

Comment: That makes two of us that didn't see it. Good catch.